# job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8.5

I have an application hosted on Tomcat 8.5 that seems to work fine but after some calls to the application api the tomcat stops working.

In the catalina.out file you see this error:

> .   ____          _            __ _ _
> /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 
>
> ( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 
>
> \/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
> '  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
> =========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
> :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)
>
> 2020-10-07 16:24:25.811  INFO 14598 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.portal.api.RestJwtApplication        : Starting RestJwtApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 162-212-130-247.cprapid.com with PID 14598 (/home/emirandafelipe/ea-tomcat85/webapps/hbportal/WEB-INF/classes started by emirandafelipe in /tmp/hsperfdata_emirandafelipe)
> 2020-10-07 16:24:25.818  INFO 14598 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.portal.api.RestJwtApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
> 2020-10-07 16:24:29.534  INFO 14598 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2828 ms
> 2020-10-07 16:24:32.368  INFO 14598 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2760c1cc, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5169c551, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@56481a56, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@29934664, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7531cee, com.homebusiness.portal.api.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter@5c8a2b87, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@69d97c37, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4d50b93e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4344dc10, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@55d1dd84, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@787d2926, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@e09ea5]
> 2020-10-07 16:24:33.464  INFO 14598 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
> 2020-10-07 16:24:36.624  INFO 14598 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.h.portal.api.RestJwtApplication        : Started RestJwtApplication in 12.004 seconds (JVM running for 22.916)
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:36.996 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [340] milliseconds.
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:37.057 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/emirandafelipe/ea-tomcat85/webapps/ROOT]
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:37.109 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/emirandafelipe/ea-tomcat85/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [52] ms
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:37.131 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10000"]
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:37.263 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:37.364 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-10001"]
> 07-Oct-2020 16:24:37.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 21266 ms
> 2020-10-07 16:24:47.473  INFO 14598 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2020-10-07 16:24:47.495  INFO 14598 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 21 ms
> job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
> at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
> at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1168)
>
> job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
> at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
> at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1168)
>
> job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
> at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
> at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1168)

This in a Linux Centos hosting with VPS.

Please, does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: If your stage is executing inside container and it has `deleteDir()`, you will have the error.